# How to set Correlation ID in spring DSL

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, blueprint-osgi, spring-dsl

How to set the correlation id in Spring DSL? The below code doesn't reflect correlation ID in Active MQ

```
<setHeader headerName="correlationId">
    <constant>IFS123</constant>
</setHeader>
```

tried with

```
<setHeader headerName="JMSCorrelationId">
    <constant>IFS456</constant>
</setHeader>
```

Comment: At which level of your workflow is your setHeader used ??

Comment: I'd be curious to know as to why you would want to set it manually and not let the AMQ Camel component do it for you?

Comment: I need to set Manually because I receive the other message after 1 or 3 months. To trace back the received message after 3 months is really tough and I need to set JMSCorrelationID manually in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is the standard JMS name which is `JMSCorrelationID` notice the upper case `ID`. You can find the name in the JMS spec: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html

Comment: Excellent Thanks a lot.